# Rstudio server start up script

Tags: startup, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am a newbie to R. I need to write a extension for R. When Rstudio is started , a  function in this package should be called which verifies and loads some data to main memory for faster access.
How can i tell R studio to call a particular function at startup which loads data into main memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the .onLoad function hook in the package.